# How are degree of freedom and gimbals related in a gyro?

Tags: flight-instruments, gyroscopic-instruments

Why does it mean to say a gyro has an even degree of freedom?

Why does this degree correspond to the number of gimbals ?

Answer (score 2):

A gyroscope can move freely about its spin axis, this equates to a single plane of movement but is not defined as a degree of freedom.  A gimbal allows movement around another plane in addition to the spin axis, this is called one degree of freedom.  The number of degrees of freedom equals the number of gimbals.

Comment: Thank you so much.